# Not able to insert element with style via execCommand("insertHTML")

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

I have one `div` with attribute `contenteditable=true`.
And I'd like to insert another div into this editable div with style attribute.
But all my attempts failed. For example:

`document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<div style='color: #000;'>")`

Style attributes always somehow being filtered out.

[Here](https://codepen.io/krave/pen/WOXRmE) is my codepen to illustrate my question.

Is there any way to insert html with style attribute attached?

BTW, how does the command `styleWithCSS` work?

Comment: `insertHTML` is not `document.write`, you've to pass a valid and complete  HTML string.

Comment: Do you mean no style attribute allowed in `insertHTML`? But I am able to insert `class`. Did I write style text in wrong format?

Comment: Nope, you'd need a closing tag, plain starting tag is not valid HTML (in case of DIV). When completing the HTML string, your code [works](https://jsfiddle.net/m6r41ypr/).

Comment: I can almost add any kinds of attribute via `insertHTML`. Such as `document.execCommand("insertHTML", true, "<div teemu></div>");`. But style is always an exception. Do you know why?

Comment: But style works as well, as you can see in the fiddle I've linked in my previous comment ...

Comment: @Teemu All right. I get it. `insertHTML` is a very intelligent. As you can see from my codepen link in the question, I set the style to `style='color: #000;'`. The font color is same as the default one. So it intelligently omit the `style`. In another snippet, I broke the `style=` sentence into several pieces and combine them with `+` . Browser can not recognize the quote surrounding `style=color: #000;` , so attributes break into `style=color:` and `#000;`. `style=color:` is not a legal style so it is dismissed and `#000;` remains. Finally I choose to use template literals to support variable